# What to do in the case of a user removing code from questions

Tags: discussion, edits, homework

At the end of last week, I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863070/numbers-divisible-by-3-recursion) which seemed like homework.  I didn't just give the answer, only some suggestions on fixing the implementation.  It seems that after I helped the user, he went back to edit his question and removed all of the code.  I rolled it back, but then he went and edited it out again. Suspicious, I looked through his ask history, and he does it to [almost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868543/recursion-array-adding-positive-numbers) [every](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868846/array-postive-numbers-not-added-properly) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844950/entering-negative-numbers-on-array) [he](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824413/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-in-my-array) has asked.  Some of them do contain the code, because other users have rolled it back.

I was hoping that the user would accept my answer, hence why I checked back today.  If he keeps removing code, should it just keep being rolled back?  How should a situation like this be handled?  I suspect that the user is doing so to avoid being found out by a teacher/professor.

Comment: Flag for moderator attention, they will probably lock the post. Given that previous commenters seem to have already let the OP know this isn't acceptable it might be worth using an "other" flag to explain the wider problem

Comment: Looks like he hasn't come back since he last made those edits. No idea if it's worth contacting him *right now*, but if you see him doing it again feel free to flag.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn will do, he might have just taken the weekend off so we'll see.

Comment: Heh... weekends.